# Django post variable as model object reference

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to pass a post variable into my view and use it as the model name for a query, the query will run but return nothing. I have hard coded the model name to verify the query indeed works, but the passed in post variable does not.

When the page loads (else block of views.py) there is just a select box where the user selects the survey type (Survey1, Survey2, etc...). When survey type is selected the page does not change by the selected survey is then loaded below the select box (if request.post block of views.py).

The commented line is supposed to use passed in post variables to achieve the same result as the uncommented line. Is there something else I need to do to make this work properly?

```
# assessment = framework_filter+".objects.filter(level__lte="+level_filter+")"
assessment = Survey1.objects.filter(level__lte=level_filter)
```

Models.py

```
class Survey1(models.Model):
    id                     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    framework              = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    identifier             = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    text                   = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    heading                = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    weight                 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    supplemental           = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category               = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    subheading             = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    level                  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    source                 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    references             = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    questions              = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Survey1"
```

Views.py

```
def assessment_view(request):
    # assessment_level = Frameworks.objects.values("framework", "securityassurancelevel").distinct()
    if request.POST:
        framework = Frameworks.objects.all()
        framework_filter = request.POST.get('framework_select').split(' ')[0]
        level_filter     = request.POST.get('framework_select').split(' ')[1]
        # assessment = framework_filter + ".objects.filter(level__lte="+level_filter+")"
        assessment = Survey1.objects.filter(level__lte=level_filter)
        template = "assessments/"+framework_filter.lower()+".html"
        data = {
            'sitetitle'       : "CAT - Assessments",
            'framework'       : framework,
            'assessment'      : assessment,
            'framework_filter': framework_filter,
            'level_filter'    : level_filter,
        }
    else:
        framework = Frameworks.objects.all()
        template  = "assessments/assessment.html"
        data   = {
            'sitetitle': "CAT - Assessments",
            'framework': framework,
        } 
    
    return render(request, template, data)
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to do such filtering. Please add the models used in this code and explain a little bit overall what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Vincent Updated. Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: One is a query the other is a string...

Comment: @thebjorn is it possible to use the string as a query? Do I need to process/format the string in another way?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: do you have a model for each survey? like, survey1, survey2 etc..?

Comment: @Vincent yes, each survey has a model based off of a json template containing the questions that I load into the db table of that model.

Comment: Why not create one Survey model and a Question model with ForeignKey relationship?

Comment: @vincent the surveys are more complicated than just questions. I am using a survey framework I built and no 2 frameworks are alike.

Comment: The frameworks don't have to be alike, they can just have a one to one relation with a survey. Still, creating a different model per survey really doesn't sound necessary. Also your current problem can be solved easier with having just one survey model